# Coverage, itself considered as a presheaf

Tags: ct.category-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, grothendieck-topology

A [coverage](http://www.ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coverage) $J$ on a category $C$ assigns to an object $U$ of $C$ a set of covering families $J(U)$. The covering families are required to be stable under pullback, which amounts to requiring that for every arrow $f: V \to U$ in $C$, there is a function $J(U) \to J(V)$ which sends a covering family $\{x_i: U_i \to U\}_{i \in I}$ of $U$ to a covering family $\{y_j: V_j \to V\}_{j \in J}$ of $V$ such that each composite $fy_j$ factors through some $x_i$. This apparently defines a presheaf on $C$, as the functor laws seem to hold.

I am interested in this presheaf and its properties. Does it have a name? For example, for every presheaf on a site we may ask whether it is a sheaf. One might want to know what are the requirements for a coverage, when considered as a presheaf as above, to be a sheaf w.r.t. itself.

Comment: In general, for a given $f$, there will be many options for the map $J(U)\to J(V)$.  It's not immediately clear to me that the choices can always be made in a way that produces a functor $J$.

Comment: What if the category has all pullbacks? Then I guess the base-change functor will do, won't it?

Comment: If you add the additional assumption that covering families are preserved by pullback (which is not part of the definition of coverage), then pullback will give you a pseudofunctor of some sort.  Pullbacks are rarely strictly associative.  You could strictify it to get an actual functor, but then the question of whether it is a sheaf will depend on the strictification chosen.

Comment: A similar sheaf appears in Fourman's *Continuous Truth I*, namely $U \mapsto C/U$. This is an internal category, and can be made into an internal site. The Grothendieck topos of internal sheaves over this internal site then has interesting properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, Andreas' comment is right: a coverage gives no specified way to "pull back" a covering family of $U$ to a covering family of $V$.  However, if you consider what *Sketches of an Elephant* calls "sifted" coverages, meaning that all covering families are sieves, then there is a canonical choice: the pullback of a sieve $R$ on $U$ along $f:V\to U$ is the sieve $f^*(R)$ consisting of all $h:W\to V$ such that $f h\in R$.

For an arbitrary sifted coverage, this pullback sieve may not be a covering family, but it always contains a covering family and thus lies in the "saturation" of the coverage.  If a sifted coverage $T$ *is* closed under pullback of sieves, in this sense, then it does yield a presheaf on $C$, which is in fact a sub-presheaf of the subobject classifier in the presheaf topos $[C^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set}]$ (which is defined by $\Omega(U) = $ the set of *all* sieves on $U$).  (If $T$ is a Grothendieck topology, then this sub-presheaf $T$ is the classifier of dense sub-presheaves.)  See also C2.1.10 in the Elephant.

I claim that this sub-presheaf $T\subseteq \Omega$ is $T$-separated iff the coverage $T$ contains at most one covering sieve of every object.  (In particular, if $T$ is a Grothendieck topology, then it must be the trivial topology.)  This condition is clearly sufficent; for necessity, suppose $R$ and $S$ are two $T$-covering sieves of an object $U$.  Then for any $f:V\to U$ in $R$, the pullback sieve $f^*(S)$ is covering.  It follows that any $T$-separated presheaf is also separated for the sieve generated by all composites $f h$ with $h\in f^*(S)$ (this sieve lies in the saturation of $T$ to a Grothendieck topology).  But this sieve is precisely $R\cap S$.

Thus, if $T\subseteq \Omega$ is $T$-separated, it is also separated for $R\cap S$ for any $R,S\in T$.  However, for any $f:V\to U$ in $R\cap S$, we have $f^*(R) = f^*(S)$ being the maximal sieve on $V$.  Thus, since $T$ is separated for $R\cap S$, we must have $R=S$; hence $U$ admits at most one $T$-covering sieve.

Now assuming $T$ satisfies this condition so that $T$ is $T$-separated, then $T$ is a $T$-sheaf whenever if $R$ is a (the) covering sieve of $U$ and for each $f:V\to U$ in $R$ we have a (the) covering sieve $S_V$ of $V$, then there is another covering sieve of $U$ (which, of course, must also be $R$) such that $f^* R = S_V$.  But when $f\in R$, then $f^*R$ is the maximal sieve on $V$, so this means that the domain of every morphism in a covering sieve is covered only by its own maximal sieve --- which is already implied by $T$ being a functor.  Such objects are called $T$-irreducible (C2.2.18 in the Elephant).

Thus there are three classes of objects in $C$: the irreducible ones, which are covered by their maximal sieve; those that are covered by some non-maximal sieve whose domains are all irreducible; and those that are not covered by any $T$-sieve.  The irreducible objects are themselves a sieve in $C$, by functoriality, as are the objects that are covered by any $T$-sieve at all.  The objects that are not covered by any $T$-sieve will be covered only by their maximal sieve in the Grothendieck topology generated by $T$, so they will be irreducible there.

In particular, the Grothendieck topology generated by $T$ is *rigid* in the sense of C2.2.18: every object is covered by the family of morphisms out of irreducible objects.  It follows that the category of $T$-sheaves is equivalent to the category of presheaves on the irreducible objects for this topology (which are those that are $T$-covered by the maximal sieve or that are not covered by any $T$-sieve).

This is perhaps not a complete answer to your question, but it shows that the condition of a sifted coverage being a sheaf for itself is very restrictive.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! Is there any relationship between $T \subseteq \Omega$ and the subobject classifier of the topos of sheaves for $T$? 

Comment: Explicitly, is the classifying map $j: \Omega \to \Omega$ of $T \subseteq \Omega$ the same as the local modality defining the sheaf topos? I guess this is the meaning of the phrase 'classifier of dense sub-presheaves'.

Comment: Yes, if $T$ is a Grothendieck topology, then when regarded as a sub-presheaf of $\Omega$, its classifying map is precisely the local modality (= Lawvere-Tierney topology) that defines the subtopos.  This is C2.1.10.  The subobject classifier in the topos of sheaves is different -- it is the classifier of _closed_ sub-presheaves, which is the equalizer of $j:\Omega\to\Omega$ and $1_\Omega$.